# Auto resize textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, keypress

I have created a simple html file that auto resizing the textarea.

The script is working (almost) perfectly.

The only problem I'm facing is that when the [enter] key is pressed the textarea is aligned only after the next keypress so by the time that [enter] key is pressed nothing is aligned. it's aligned itself only after next keypress.

Here is my simple code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Gangina Auto Resize</title>
<style>
 textarea
  {
    display:block;
    resize:none;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txtArea" onkeypress="onTestChange();"></textarea>
<script>
function onTestChange()
  {
    var ta = document.getElementById("txtArea");
    ta.style.height = ta.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to add a fake `\n` to the equation but it wasn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need `keyup`

```js
function onTestChange() {
  var ta = document.getElementById("txtArea");
  ta.style.height = ta.scrollHeight + 'px'
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea" onkeyup="onTestChange();"></textarea>
```

Comment: Working :D But the text is jumping in a funny way when [enter] key is pressed and then calibarate itself again .